# Values from dynamically produced checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox, dynamically-generated

I am trying to get the values of a dynamically created set of checkboxes in PHP but apparently I couldn't get it. The source codes are below.

The "managestaff.php" page would allow searching for staff via their names and throws out a list of names with checkboxes for the admin to check them and click on a "delete" button at the bottom to delete the staff whom are being checked.

The deletion would be done on "deletestaff.php" as the "delete" button on "managestaff.php" simply forwards these values to "deletestaff.php" to do deletion work of the staff.

"managestaff.php" page codes:

```
<b><h3>Manage Staff</h3></b><br/>

<form action="managestaff.php" method="POST">
<input name="form" type="hidden" id="form" value="true">
<table width=300>
    <tr>
        <td width=112>Staff Name: </td>
        <td width=188><input type="text" class="textfield" name="sname" /><br/></td>
    </tr>
</table><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form']) && (isset($_POST['sname'])) && $_POST['form'] == 'true') {

$space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$staffname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
$query = 'SELECT * from staff where staffname like \'%' . $staffname . '%\'';

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Staff ID' . $space . '</th><th>Staff Name' . $space . '</th></tr>';
    echo '<form action="deletestaff.php" method="POST">';
    echo '<input name="delstaffform" type="hidden">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['staffid'] . '</td><td>' . $row['staffname'] . '</td>';

        // :Begin - dynamic checkbox generation for deleting staff
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="delstaff" value="' . $row['staffid'] . '"                 />';
        echo '</td>';
        // :End
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '<tr align="right"><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="delete"/></td></tr>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</table>';

}
}
?>
```

"deletestaff.php" page codes:

```
<?php
print_r('POST: ' . $_POST);

echo '<br>';

if (isset($_POST['delstaffform']) && isset($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
    echo 'Submission of delstaffform FOUND !';
    echo 'Staff to delete' . $HTTP_POST_VARS['delstaff'];
}
else{
    echo 'Submission of delstaffform NOT FOUND !';
}
?>
```

The "deletestaff.php" doesn't do delete for now as it's a test page.

The current output I get is "Submission of delstaffform NOT FOUND !".

Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: <input name="delstaffform" type="hidden" --- is the end of that line a typo?

Comment: No it is not. I was experimenting with using hidden fields previously to grab the checkboxes values.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that the tag isn't closed. The > is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delstaff[]" value="' . $row['staffid'] . '"/>';
```

print_r your $_POST and you'll see it sticks your submissions nicely into an array for you.

Comment: I did the following in the "deletestaff.php" page as following:

"print_r('POST: '.$_POST);"

The output was:

"POST: Array". I am not familiar with what to do next. Please advise.

Comment: try print_r($_POST) - you can't use . to concatenate an array to a string. Also make sure you have boxes checked.

Comment: Oh yeah, and view source if the output is screwy. print_r doesn't add html so the line breaks don't show up if you just view the output in a browser.

Comment: I have checked the boxes before hitting the button to activate the codes. Do I view the source on the "managestaff.php" or the output at the "deletestaff.php" ?

Comment: Wherever your print_r output is.

Comment: My output when viewing source for the print_r is "POST: Array". That's all it prints.

Comment: Read my 1st comment response again and follow it this time. I'm going to bed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delstaff']) && is_array($_POST['delstaff'])) {

    echo 'Submission of delstaffform FOUND !';

    $array = $_POST["delstaff"];

    foreach($array as $value){
        echo "<br>Value: ".$value."<br>";
    }

} else {
    echo 'Submission of delstaffform NOT FOUND !';
}
?>
```

Found the answer on my own but nevertheless you are helpful :D . Thanks a lot.